# When you are standing in a running train if you jump means will you be in same place or will you be in front or back?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, relative-motion

When you are standing in a running train if you jump means will you be in same place or will you be in front or back?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7479/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14993/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

When you jump up you keep the same horizontal speed as the train. So with respect to the train, you stay on the same place, and with respect to somebody standing outside the train, you move forward together with the train.