# How much impact would it make in science if the speed of light is discovered to be variable?

Tags: speed-of-light

So if such a thing happens, how would it alter current physics?

Comment: Well, not that much if you think about it

Comment: This is too broad a question. Have a read throught the [Wikipedia article on VSL theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light) and google [variable speed of light cosmology](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=variable%20speed%20of%20light%20cosmology) then come back to us if you have a specific question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34874/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few results of [variable speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light):

[Ellis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_F._R._Ellis) [claimed](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10714-007-0396-4) that any varying c theory

1. must redefine distance measurements
2. must provide an alternative expression for the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)) in
   general relativity
3. might contradict [Lorentz invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance)
4. must modify [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations)
5. must be done consistently with respect to all other physical
   theories