# $c$ slowing down rather than universe expanding?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion

Can the Friedmann equations be reformulated with taking the universe as being rigid and instead have the vacuum-speed of light in the void decrease over time? So, not changing any equations, just interpreting them differently? Or does that way of looking at it not work for some reason?

Comment: I know the concept of tired light, but that's a bit different and is solely an explanation for red-shift. What I ask is whether - without changing the friedman-equations, they can be interpreted as c decreasing simply by assuming another variable as being the constant (instead of c being the constant)

Comment: Proposals and papers are around. With no answers, look for "tired light" for one aspect and "light slowing down, Davies". Also in ArXiv ....

Comment: You want to know if there is a change in length scales over time so that the velocity of light decreases over time even though it is always "c" and that the cosmological redshift can, somehow I do not know how, be explained by this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73114/2451