# Instead of the universe accelerating its expansion, could non-constant constants also explain the phenomena?

Tags: astrophysics, space-expansion, physical-constants, dark-energy

The data gathered led physicists and astronomers to the conclusion that the universe is accelerating its expansion and therefore to theories about dark energy.  My question is, could certian constants like plank's constant and the G, the universal constant of gravitation, and perhaps other so called constants that have a role to play in the accelerating universe calculations, could in fact not be constant and thus explain the data?

Comment: Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-variation_of_fundamental_constants

Comment: @Jon Custer So the answer is probably yes, but I am sure they have considered this more reasonable explanation before inventing dark energy.

Comment: Yes. See [Is the FRW metric physically distinguishable from a metric with a speed of light that changes over time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557858/37364)