# Does time expand?

Tags: spacetime, time, space-expansion, time-dilation, observers

If the time component of spacetime does not "expand" in the sense that space expands, doesn't that imply that time must already exist in its entirety, past and future? I believe I have seen the opinion expressed by popular physicists that time could be expanding. That would nicely explain how the future comes to exist. Is the non-expanding character of time physically real or is it just an aspect of the way we measure things?

Comment: Time dilates much like space in relativity, if that is what your question is referring to? See Lorentz Transform for more.

Comment: [Is the FRW metric physically distinguishable from a metric with a speed of light that changes over time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557858/37364)