# What is the speed of light from a star moving towards a observer.?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, faster-than-light

We can say that in vacuum speed of light is constant. But if the star is moving with a certain velocity does it add that velocity to the velocity of photons emitted out of that star?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Look for ''relativistic velocity addition rule'' on your best friend, Google. Or else, use the search tab on this website. This has been answered before I think. Cheers :)

Comment: The answer would be a duplicate from e.g. here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2230/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to special relativity's postulates, the speed of light in a vacuum is the same for all observers, regardless of the motion of the light source.

You may want to read the [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect). It refers to the change in frequency of light due to motion of observer and/or source.