# How can light have the same speed for all observers?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames

I'm a little confused on this. If you're travelling at, say, 10% of the speed of light then light is travelling at 3x10^8 ms^(-1) relative to you. If you're moving at 80% of the speed of light and light is also travelling at 3x10^8 ms^(-1). For the second case, wouldnt light have to accelerate and move at a greater velocity in order to maintain the 3x10^8 ms^(-1) speed...? Then that means the actual speed of light relative to a stationary observer would be greater than 3x10^8 ms^(-1) . I might have confused myself even more here...

Comment: It's not a bad thing to be confused at first by this since, essentially, *everyone* is initially confused by this.  However, this very well might be the *most* frequently asked question of all the frequently asked questions about special relativity.  In other words, please take the time to do just a bit more research on this most frequently asked question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2230/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @user58953 -- I started an answer with a numerical example before the question was closed, but I saw there was no answer with a similar numerical example to the earlier similar question, so I added my answer there--if you think such an example would be helpful, go [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142330/59406).