# cancelling the speed of a moving object

Tags: speed

Hi I can't seem to get this thought out of my head.  Is the light from a moving object begin from a zero position.  If for a brief instant the object were to stop would that cause the negation of the speed of the moving object to be added to c?

Comment: The speed of light is constant and is not affected by the speed of the source.  If Alice stands still (relative to you) while Bob bicycles toward you at a speed of .99c and Carol bicycles away from you at a speed of .99c, all three light  beams will travel toward you at the same speed c.   This fact (or observation or postulate) is the heart of Einstein's relativity theory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and how is the speed of light in vacuum constant, i.e., independent of reference frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/why-and-how-is-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum-constant-i-e-independent-of-refer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and how is the speed of light in vacuum constant, i.e., independent of reference frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/why-and-how-is-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum-constant-i-e-independent-of-refer)

Answer (score 1):

> the object were to stop would that cause the negation of the speed of the moving object to be added to c?

No. The *speed* of light coming from an object is completely independent of the motion of that object. Very simply, "it just doesn't work that way".

There are changes in the light due to motion, but just not the speed. The energy, for instance, will change, which is why you have redshift and blueshift.