# Can we have a photon at rest?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, speed-of-light

Theoretically, Photons don't have rest mass but they behave as material particles in many cases.
But is it possible to stop a photon without destroying it ie. Can we slow it down so much to make it almost at rest and if not Why?

Comment: @johnrennie They are different and just look apparently same

Comment: They look like duplicates to me. If you can clarify exactly what you're asking and why the linked question doesn't answer it then I'd be happy to reopen. Note that if you're asking about the photon speed in vacuum then that is always $c$ for all observers. Photon speed only varies in a medium.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am asking why they can't be stopped is there any law violation and the question is genuine and the other one is not the same

Comment: Are you asking why the speed of photons is always $c$ in a vacuum? As the answers to the other question show photons can be stopped in a  medium. In that case it would be a duplicate of [Why and how is the speed of light in vacuum constant, i.e., independent of reference frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/why-and-how-is-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum-constant-i-e-independent-of-refer)

Comment: @johnrennie https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394116/ This is also a duplicate why don't you bother about this

Answer (score 3):

No, we **cannot** make photons travel at any value other than the speed of light. It is a postulate of the theory of relativity and it works because solutions to the equations of electromagnetism indicate that light/photons must travel at a constant speed regardless of observer. A way to think of it is like, **because** photons have zero rest mass that is why they can travel at the only other speed available that is less than the speed of light, that is: light speed.

One can *presumably* *slow down* light in optically denser media but in reality the light *does* travel at $c$ while bouncing and interacting with atoms in the medium so it only *seems* that light is slowed down by refraction.

Comment: So photons don't slow in a medium do they keep colliding which makes them apparently slow?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In between interactions of absorption and re-emissions the photons always travel at $c$ but it's the extra time due to these interactions that makes it *seem* that light is slowed down.