# Is the speed of light greater if traveling at an initial velocity greater than zero?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

I'm reading "a brief history of time" and he states "the speed of light should be the same whatever the speed of the source, and this has been confirmed," (24). Why is it not increased if it has an initial velocity- if you shine your headlights while driving versus while parked, should it not be greater? I'm supposing it has to do with there being no absolute space/position, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and how is the speed of light in vacuum constant, i.e., independent of reference frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2230/)

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange!  It looks like your question has already been asked before, so it may end up being closed as a duplicate.  If the previous answers don't answer your current question, please edit your question to add more detail and explain what's missing from the previous answers.